# ¿Por que no me aplica Editable a mi tabla?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

El problema que tengo es que tengo una tabla en `HTML` de la siguiente manera

```
<!-- TABLA DETALLES PRODUCTOS -->
<div class="col-md-12">
<table id="TableProducts" class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
<thead>
<tr class="active">
<td><strong>ID Producto</strong></td>
<td><strong>Nombre Producto</strong></td>
<td><strong>Caracteristicas</strong></td>
<td><strong>Muestras</strong></td>
<td><strong>Cantidad</strong></td>
<td><strong>Precio</strong></td>
<td><strong>Descuento</strong></td>
<td><strong>IVA</strong></td>
<td><strong>Retención IVA</strong></td>
<td><strong>Total</strong></td>
<td><strong></strong></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<!-- FIN TABLA DETALLES PRODUCTOS -->
```

Yo agrego dentro del div una fila, de la siguiente manera con `jquery`

```
var fila = "<td>" + $.trim(idProduct) + "</td>";
fila += "<tr><td>" + $.trim(response.d.nombreProducto) + "</td>";
fila += '<td onclick="OpenModal(\'' + $.trim(idProduct) + '\', \'' + precio + '\');">XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX</td>';
fila += "<td><center><input type='radio'></center></td>";
fila += "<td><a id='tableccant'>1</a></td>";
fila += "<td><a id='tablecprice'>0</a></td>";
fila += "<td><a id='tablecdescc'>0</a></td>";
fila += "<td>IVA</td>";
fila += "<td>RIVA</td>";
fila += "<td>TOTAL</td>";
fila += "<td><a class='text-danger delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td></tr>";
var ElementoHTML = $(fila);
$('#TableProducts').append(ElementoHTML);
```

Después de eso tengo una linea en donde mando llamar un método en donde aplico el plugin de `editable de bootstrap` de la siguiente manera

```
//Se puede editar la tabla de dos maneras gracias al plugin
//La primera es por medio de popo up y la otra es por inline

$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = "inline";

// Sección productos
$("#tableccant").editable();
$("#tablecprice").editable();
$("#tablecdescc").editable();
```

Mi problema es que cuando agrego la primera fila, me funciona de maravilla, pero cuando agrego mas filas no me aplica el `plugin`, alguien sabe a cual podría ser el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en los `id` ya que estos deben ser **Únicos** en todo el DOM, de no ser así, Javascript solo toma el primero.

Ahora si quieres que funcione en todos los elementos utiliza clases, de tal manera que tu código quedaría así:

```
var fila = "<td>" + $.trim(idProduct) + "</td>";
fila += "<tr><td>" + $.trim(response.d.nombreProducto) + "</td>";
fila += '<td onclick="OpenModal(\'' + $.trim(idProduct) + '\', \'' + precio + '\');">XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX</td>';
fila += "<td><center><input type='radio'></center></td>";
fila += "<td><a class='tableccant'>1</a></td>";
fila += "<td><a class='tablecprice'>0</a></td>";
fila += "<td><a class='tablecdescc'>0</a></td>";
fila += "<td>IVA</td>";
fila += "<td>RIVA</td>";
fila += "<td>TOTAL</td>";
fila += "<td><a class='text-danger delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td></tr>";
var ElementoHTML = $(fila);
$('#TableProducts').append(ElementoHTML);
```

y en javascript dejarías lo siguiente:

```
$(".tableccant").editable();
$(".tablecprice").editable();
$(".tablecdescc").editable();
```

Pero puede surgir un problema debido a tu contenido dinámico por lo que yo lo dejaría de esta forma:

```
$("table").find(".tableccant").editable();
$("table").find(".tablecprice").editable();
$("table").find(".tablecdescc").editable();
```

Comment: Gracias JuankGlezz tu explicación me sirvió de maravilla, ya que me ayudo a encontrar una solución, ademas de entender que el problema era el uso de el mismo `id`

Answer (score 1):

Cuando generas este html:

```
fila += "<td><a id='tableccant'>1</a></td>";
fila += "<td><a id='tablecprice'>0</a></td>";
fila += "<td><a id='tablecdescc'>0</a></td>";
```

Estas agregando multiples elementos con el mismo `id="tableccant"`. Por lo que cuando buscas en elemento por el id, siempre retornara el primer elemento con ese id.

Mira un ejemplo:

```js
$("#id-1").css("background", "blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id-1">Div 1</div>
<div id="id-1">Div 2</div>
```

Debes de buscar la manera de generar el id dinamicamente, obtener ese id y aplicar el estilo que deseas.

Puedes también cambiar el id por una clase y hacer lo siguiente:

```
fila += "<td><a class='tableccant'>1</a></td>";
```

Javascript:

```
$(".tableccant").editable();
```

Comment: Gracias Einer me funciono de maravilla y exactamente como tu comentaste el problema era con los `id`, la solución fue cambiar el `id` por una `clase`

Comment: Excelente! Me alegra saber que lo solucionaste.